# what does this attempted trojan horse code do?

Tags: c, malware

It looks like this just sends a ping, but whats the point of that when you can just use ping?

```
/* WARNING: this is someone's attempt at writing a malware trojan. Do not
   compile and *definitely* don't install. I added an exit as the
   first line to avoid mishaps - msw */
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    exit(1);
    unsigned int pid = 0;
    char buffer[2];
    char *args[] = {
        "/bin/ping",
        "-c",
        "5",
        NULL,
        NULL
    };

    if (argc != 2)
        return 0;

    args[3] = strdup(argv[1]);
    for (;;)
    {
        gets(buffer); /* FTW */

        if (buffer[0] == 0x6e)
            break;

        switch (pid = fork())
        {
            case -1:
                printf("Error Forking\n");
                exit(255);
            case 0:
                execvp(args[0], args);
                exit(1);
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return 255;
}
```

Comment: I dont see how compiling and running this could mess up your computer, as long as you use it safely. From what i gather after looking at it more if you pass an IP address to it, it will repeatedly ping that 5 times everytime you press enter until your next input is 'n'

Comment: The key is what happens to the storage used by args when you type arbitrary length strings into buffer. Like I wrote, it isn't a good hack, but it is an attempt and it probably won't bite you as most people don't type at ping. But perhaps there's an exploit on a particular version of ping say under cygwin, having this binary around named ping could be a vector for an attack. Unlikely, but someone wrote this code with intention, maybe he knows some hole you don't.

Comment: Oh, and since this code has no inherent merit, there's even less reason to build/run/install it.

Comment: couldnt this serve multiple purpose then? it looks like a POD but w/ normal pings, (just did some research), if someone has greater bandwith than their target couldnt this be used to "own them?"

Comment: So who wrote this code? And who do you want to "own" with it? And why does it look suspiciously like your next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889400/can-you-declare-data-in-a-char-using-hex ? And couldn't you just hit the other kid with a bat instead? It's far more direct than getting him to run obfuscated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sure that `ping` is called with the arguments `-c 5`. Which is stupid, because a shell script or alias would be easier to read and faster to write.

Comment: I think you missed the bit that ping(8) doesn't read from stdin where this code does repeatedly until someone types a line beginning with 'n'. This is an attempt at a trojan.

Answer (score 4):

It's a hack - or an attempt at a hack - to get arbitrary code run in a privileged mode. Ping needs to run SUID root to get a raw socket for an ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST and the intentional buffer overrun in `gets(buffer)` is intended to pass junk to ping.

I don't see how this could work in practice, but you shouldn't compile and run it.

Answer (score 0):

This program basically emulates a simple shell program.  A shell program is going to take the arguments of another program as input and launch that specified program in a new process.  The program you have above is just hard coded for one specific program (ping in this case) and is very simple.

A shell program makes working with the operating system more user friendly by providing an interface to boot up programs.

Comment: Not even a shell program. Just an alias.