# can you declare data in a char** using hex?

Tags: c

lets say I have this

```
char *something[] = { 
    "/bi", 
    "-c", 
    "5", 
    NULL, 
    NULL 
};
```

but I want to declare it in hex, how would I do this; compiler keeps erroring out on me:

```
char *something[] = { 
    {0x2f,0x62,0x69},
    {0x2d,0x63},
    {0x35},
    {0x00}, 
    {0x00}
};
```

to add something else to this, is 0x00 ALWAYS null? does 0x00 always translate to NULL on systems where NULL is -1 for example?

Comment: To answer the edit, any integral constant expression that evaluates to `0` (e.g., `0`, `0x0`, `1-1`) can be used as the null pointer constant.

Comment: You do realise your two code snippets are not the same?  `"-c"` is equivalent to `{0x2d,0x63, 0x00}` for instance.  and the last two items are null pointers in the first example and pointers to empty strings in the second.

Comment: Actually, the second part of my comment might be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use hexadecimal escape sequences within a string literal.  For example:

```
char *something[] = { 
    "\x2f\x62\x69",
    "\x2d\x63"
};
```

Comment: awsome, are they auto null terminated or does a \x00 need to be added at the end of each index?

Comment: @bstullkid:  They are just string literals with escape sequences inside of them, so, yes, they are null-terminated.

Comment: The string literals in double quotes are auto NUL-terminated (with the character '\0', i.e. zero), but the array of pointers to char is not auto NULL-terminated with a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about `NULL` and the null pointer: the macro `NULL` is *always* 0.  The compiler then converts that to an appropriate null pointer.  [The comp.lang.c FAQ has an entire section explaining this more thoroughly](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html).

Comment: +1 for making the assumption that script-kiddie-gamerz-dude will actually read. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888915/what-does-this-attempted-trojan-horse-code-do/2888941#2888941